# Delphi: How to check if webbrowser has successfully loaded the page?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, twebbrowser

I have a simple code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.foo.com');
```

But of course sometimes the browsing fails and the browser displays the error message.
How can I catch when this happens?
I want this so that I can make a some sort of a custom log.

Comment: I wonder if you could check TWebBrowser.ReadyState for success (maybe in a while loop or using TTimer). If ReadyState doesn't return READYSTATE_COMPLETE in a reasonable time, raise your own error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the the OnNavigateError event handler is called when there is a problem.

Comment: Strange but it seems that my TWebBrowser doesn't support OnNavigateError even doe I have found on MSDN that it is applied to it. Why is this? I am using Delphi7 btw.

Comment: Nope, I am absolutely sure that OnNavigateError is missing. Infact `WebBrowser1.onNavigateError:=<function>;` throws an error telling that `onNavigateError` is not declared. What should I do?

Comment: @SmRndGuy: You're right; it's not there in D7. (D7 imports an extremely old version of the IE type library (`SHDocVw`). You may need to remove it and import a newer version of the type library to work with more modern versions of IE or use something like the freeware [TEmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/product.html), which exposes more of the functionality.

Comment: k. Now that I know what is the problem I can go on browsing and solving it. Thankyou.